# Submitting form data without page refresh oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a very complex form page in oracle apex. and its from a large table with many columns
When i save on this form, the entire page is submitted and refreshed by default in oracle apex. For this page it takes about 7 to 10 seconds to totally refresh and update the table etc.

I would like to know if there is something i can do to update table rows without having to refresh the entire page.

I kind of know that you can write an update statement to do this .but is there a more elegant solution in apex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dynamic actions](http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2013/10/apex-101-dynamic-actions.html) to execute PL/SQL on demand from a press of a button, or some other action.

The trade-off comes as you can't utilise validations/computations/page processes.

But if it's taking 10 seconds to do all that work, I would suggest you have some performance tuning to consider.

Comment: ok cool. i did alot of performance tuning on he page already. its really crazy.